# Getting "variable undefined" error when trying to reset the variable's value

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run through a set of documents and reset the value of `cur_pg`, but get the following error:

> Script Variable is undefined: 'cur_pg' ...

My code is such:

```
option explicit

'----------------- OnStartProcess -----------------
function OnStartProcess
  Line.value = empty
  Page.value = empty
  cur_pg = 0
  cur_line = 0
end function

''----------------- OnRecord -----------------
function OnRecord
  dim s: s = this.GetLine()
  dim pgn
  pgn =  this.GetPageNumber()
  if cur_pg.value <> pgn then cur_line.value = 1
  trg.Message s
  trg.Message dictin.P1.value
  if trg.strlib.InStr(s, Search.value )>0 then
    Line.value = Line.value & cur_line.value & ","
    Page.value = Page.value & this.GetPageNumber() & ","
  end if
  cur_line.value = cur_line.value  + 1
end function

'----------------- OnFinishProcess -----------------
function OnFinishProcess
  line.value = trg.strlib.Chop( line.value )
  page.value = trg.strlib.Chop( page.value )
  trg.Message line.value & " - " & page.value
end function
```

Gow do I define this variable?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you have `Option Explicit` set on your code.

This causes VB to make sure that all variables you use throughout your code have been declared.

If you remove `Option Explicit` (or set `Option Explicit Off`) you will be able to use variables that have not been explicitly declared.

My personal preference is to always use explicit declaration though.  If you wish to go down this route, simply ensure that you `Dim` your variables before using them.

For more information [visit the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx).

Comment: Also, since apparently variable initialization and use are in different functions, the declaration must be in the global scope.